# Saving/Reloading data in android activities, possibly with an seperate class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, restore

I am new to android and am working on a fairly basic android application where users are able to create items that are added to a ListView. On creation of each item I create a instance of the 'clicker' class which keeps track of each items name/tick count/other statistics.

when on of the items in the list are clicked it launches a general activity, used by all of the items. I pass the 'clicker' class object to the activity so that it may construct initialize the textviews.

This is what happens when a list item is clicked (the clicker instances are created in a hashmap named clickers, so I first retrieve the key, then call clickers.get(key))

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // pass along some ID so that the new activity can retrieve info
    String clickedName = clickerListItems.get(arg2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClickerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("clickerName", clickers.get(clickedName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is how the general activity receives the info

```
public class ClickerActivity extends Activity {
    protected Clicker currentClicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clicker);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        currentClicker = (Clicker) i.getSerializableExtra("clickerName");

        TextView clickerHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickerHeader);
        clickerHeader.setText(currentClicker.getName());

        final TextView countDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countText);
        countDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(currentClicker.getCount()));

        final Button incrementButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incrementButton);
        final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
         (continues)
```

here's what the general activity looks like to add some perspective. It's fairly plain right now seeing as I am just starting out.

[image]

The issue is that say I click on item A of the ListView and increment it's counter (one of the stats) and then press the back button to return to the List Activity. Now if I click on the same listitem to reload the activity none of the data seems to have been saved. Is the clicker class instance not actually being altered? How do I save the info or restore the info? I would do something onRestoreInstanceState but since this is an activity that may be loaded by any item in the list that wouldn't work, right?

If there any clarification is required please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shared preferences**, to preserve those values.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

By using this, none of your data will be lost. Just make sure that when you are starting the app again *after killing it*, you **reset** the values stored, so that your values are saved for *activity* relaunch, but not for *app* relaunch (*unless* you want it for that too).

**EDIT:** You can also put all your main code into an **Asynctask()**, so that processing would be done in the background and it would be kept alive even when you come out of the app.

Comment: I see that this works for basic data like saving integers and strings, but I will also eventually be needed to store more complex data like a record of days that the clicker was incremented and the how many clicks per day. This is why I was trying to all the info in the clicker class. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could also store that complex data in simple form on *sharedpreferences*. Basically your record of days could be something like an arraylist or hashmap of strings and how many clicks per day, would be arraylist of integers. I doubt this would make a very big difference.

Comment: If you want to store data for days together, something like shared preferences would be a good option for you. One more suggestion would be: see my edit.

Comment: Very true - I have it saving data now. I greatly appreciate the suggestion and the explanation.